# How to get laser data from gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have modeled a robot with a laser sensor. Whenever it sees anything it range I want to set some force to a joint. I don't understand how to get the laser data via gazebo.

Any help will be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16204/how-to-get-laser-data-from-gazebo?/) by [lory18](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3258/lory18/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-05-19**:
What version of gazebo are you using?

**Comment by [lory18](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3258/lory18/) on 2017-05-19**:
i'm using gazebo ver 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are a couple ways to get the laser data. These work for both the Gpu based ray sensor and CPU based ray sensor, but I'll assume the former. If you're using the CPU based sensor just remove `Gpu` from everything.

- [Follow this tutorial to subscribe](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=topics_subscribed&cat=transport) to the gazebo topic laser data

**OR**

- Implement a sensor plugin based on [GpuRayPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/cddf2613ce88d814cbe599aded96b356a5ffefd0/plugins/GpuRayPlugin.cc?at=gazebo7&fileviewer=file-view-default)

The laser data topic uses publishes a protobuf message every time the sensor makes a measurement. The message definition is [LaserScanStamped](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/cddf2613ce88d814cbe599aded96b356a5ffefd0/gazebo/msgs/laserscan_stamped.proto?at=gazebo7&fileviewer=file-view-default) which is a time stamped [LaserScan](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/cddf2613ce88d814cbe599aded96b356a5ffefd0/gazebo/msgs/laserscan.proto?at=gazebo7&fileviewer=file-view-default) message. You can see how it gets populated [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/cddf2613ce88d814cbe599aded96b356a5ffefd0/gazebo/sensors/GpuRaySensor.cc?at=gazebo7&fileviewer=file-view-default#GpuRaySensor.cc-696).

[This tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_hello_world&cat=write_plugin) shows how you implement a plugin. You'll want to implementing a sensor plugin and inherit from [GpuRayPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/cddf2613ce88d814cbe599aded96b356a5ffefd0/plugins/GpuRayPlugin.cc?at=gazebo7&fileviewer=file-view-default). Specifically your code will go in [OnNewLaserFrame](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/cddf2613ce88d814cbe599aded96b356a5ffefd0/plugins/GpuRayPlugin.cc?at=gazebo7&fileviewer=file-view-default#GpuRayPlugin.cc-55)

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lory18](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3258/lory18/) on 2017-05-22**:
Thanks for the answer, i was missing the part of extrapolating data from msgs, after reading the code it's more clear!